# I am trying to create a resume registry using php PDO prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement, sql-insert

I am trying to insert form data to my profile table when I click the add button, but whenever I test my code below it just reloads my add.php page and clears the form instead of adding it to my table.

add.php code:

```
<?php
//connection to the database
$pdo = require_once 'pdo.php';

session_start();

//if user is not logged in redirect back to index.php with an error message
if(!isset($_SESSION['user_id'])){
    die("ACCESS DENIED");
    return;
}

//if the user requested cancel go back to index.php
if(isset($_POST['cancel'])){
    header('Location: index.php');
    return;
}

//handling incoming data
$uid = $_SESSION['user_id'];
if (isset($_POST['first_name']) && isset($_POST['last_name']) &&
isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['headline']) && isset($_POST['summary'])){

    if (strlen($_POST['first_name']) == 0 || strlen($_POST['last_name']) == 0 ||
    strlen($_POST['email']) || strlen($_POST['headline']) == 0 || strlen($_POST['summary']) == 0){
        $_SESSION['error'] = "All fields are required";
        header("Location: add.php");
        return;
    }

    if(strpos($_POST['email'], '@') === false){
        $_SESSION['error'] = "Email address must contain @";
        header("Location: add.php");
        return;
    }

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO profile
    (user_id, first_name, last_name, email, headline, summary)
    VALUES ( :uid, :fn, :ln, :em, :he, :su)');
    $stmt->execute(array(
    ':uid' => $uid,
    ':fn' => $_POST['first_name'],
    ':ln' => $_POST['last_name'],
    ':em' => $_POST['email'],
    ':he' => $_POST['headline'],
    ':su' => $_POST['summary'])
    );

    $_SESSION['success'] = "profile added";
    header("location: index.php");
    return;

}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Mandla'ke Makondo's Profile Add</title>
<!-- bootstrap.php - this is HTML -->

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" 
    href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
    integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" 
    crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" 
    href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" 
    integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" 
    crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<h1>Adding Profile for UMSI</h1>
<form method="post" action="index.php">
<p>First Name:
<input type="text" name="first_name" size="60"/></p>
<p>Last Name:
<input type="text" name="last_name" size="60"/></p>
<p>Email:
<input type="text" name="email" size="30"/></p>
<p>Headline:<br/>
<input type="text" name="headline" size="80"/></p>
<p>Summary:<br/>
<textarea name="summary" rows="8" cols="80"></textarea>
<p>
<input type="submit" name="add" value="Add">
<input type="submit" name="cancel" value="Cancel">
</p>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

here I created my connection to the database using pdo connection and also require my config.php file for database sign in credentials
here is my pdo.php code:

```
<?php
require_once 'config.php';
    //setting DSN
    $dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname;charset=UTF8";


    //creating a PDO instance
try{

    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    
    if($pdo){
     echo "database connected Successfully";
    return;
}

}catch(PDOException $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
    
?>
```

my database sign in credentials are in this file, the username, password and dbname are not necessarily correct, I only changed them for the sake of asking.
here is my config.php code:

```
<?php
    //my variables
    $host = 'localhost';
    $user = 'myusername';
    $password = 'mypass';
    $dbname = 'mydb';

?>
```

my index.php code has a static display for the profile entries, I wanted to be able to add the profiles first so I can make it dynamically display the profiles but here is my index.php code:

```
<?php 
 session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Mandla'ke Makondo's Resume Registry</title>
<!-- bootstrap.php - this is HTML -->

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" 
    href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
    integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" 
    crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" 
    href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" 
    integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" 
    crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<h1>Mandla'ke Makondo's Resume Registry</h1>
<p>
    <?php 
    if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])){

      echo "  <a href='logout.php'>Logout</a>";
    
    }

    if(!isset($_SESSION['user_id'])){

    echo "<a href='login.php'>Please log in</a>";    
        
    }
    ?>
</p>


<?php
    if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])){
        echo"<table border = '1'>
        <tr><th>Name</th><th>Headline</th><th>Action</th><tr><tr><td>
        <a href='view.php?profile_id=5634'>srghrsh yteu yt uuu</a></td><td>
        eyetu e5u5</td><td><a href = 'edit.php'>Edit</a> <a href = 'delete.php'>Delete</a></td></tr>
        </table>";
        echo "<a href='add.php'>Add New Entry</a>";
    }

    if(!isset($_SESSION['user_id'])){
        echo "<table border='1'>
        <tr><th>Name</th><th>Headline</th>
        <tr>
        <tr><td>
        <a href='view.php?profile_id=5634'>srghrsh yteu yt uuu</a></td><td>
        eyetu e5u5</td></tr>
        </table>";
    }
?>
</div>
</body>

    enter code here
<?php 
 session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Mandla'ke Makondo's Resume Registry</title>
<!-- bootstrap.php - this is HTML -->

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" 
    href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
    integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" 
    crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" 
    href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" 
    integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" 
    crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<h1>Mandla'ke Makondo's Resume Registry</h1>
<p>
    <?php 
    if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])){

      echo "  <a href='logout.php'>Logout</a>";
    
    }

    if(!isset($_SESSION['user_id'])){

    echo "<a href='login.php'>Please log in</a>";    
        
    }
    ?>
</p>


<?php
    if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])){
        echo"<table border = '1'>
        <tr><th>Name</th><th>Headline</th><th>Action</th><tr><tr><td>
        <a href='view.php?profile_id=5634'>srghrsh yteu yt uuu</a></td><td>
        eyetu e5u5</td><td><a href = 'edit.php'>Edit</a> <a href = 'delete.php'>Delete</a></td></tr>
        </table>";
        echo "<a href='add.php'>Add New Entry</a>";
    }

    if(!isset($_SESSION['user_id'])){
        echo "<table border='1'>
        <tr><th>Name</th><th>Headline</th>
        <tr>
        <tr><td>
        <a href='view.php?profile_id=5634'>srghrsh yteu yt uuu</a></td><td>
        eyetu e5u5</td></tr>
        </table>";
    }
?>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Your form action points to `index.php`, can we see that as well?

Comment: There seems to be a difference when you check the `strlen` of everything - when you check for `email` you don't compare to zero. I think this means it'll give a false negative and throw you out to `add.php` but it would have set the error-message session variable to give you a hint on what went wrong.